# Find all points with integer coordinates inside tetrahedron

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates, interpolation

I am trying to find all the points with integer coordinates that lie inside of a tetrahedron (I want to somehow be able to loop through them). I know the coordinates of the four points (A, B, C, D) that define the tetrahedron.

What I'm currently doing is I find the bounding box of the tetrahedron (minimum and maximum x, y, z coordinates of A, B, C, D) and then do a loop through all of the points inside the bounding box. For every such point, I calculate the barycentric coordinates (using [the equations from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29#Barycentric_coordinates_on_tetrahedra)) and check if the point is inside the tetrahedron (if any of the barycentric coordinates is negative or bigger than 1, the point isn't inside).

Is there a better way to do this? Currently there is around 1/6 chance that the point I am testing (from the bounding box) really lies inside the tetrahedron, so I think I'm doing too many unnecessary computations.

I am working with a list of tetrahedra that I generated by triangulating a bigger volume (I am expanding the volume and want to interpolate the missing values using tetrahedral interpolation). I am not using any external libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another idea for improving:

check if a "rod" parrallel to z-axis (i.e. x=4, y=6) runs through the tetrahedron. If not, no values with (x=4, y=5, z) can be inside.

Else, find where the rod intersects the edge of the tetrahedron (by finding out where the planes that make up the edge of the tetrahedron intersect it).

Say these planes intersect at z=1.3 and z= 10.04. Then you know all points (4,5, 2)  to (4,5,10) are inside.

Repeat for all values of x and y.

This should be faster in practice, because it will save you 1 loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is the correct one. There are some possible optimisations, which might be worth it or not depending on the requirements. For example:

There is an easier way to check if a given point is inside or outside of the tetrahedron.
It amounts to checking the which half-space the point belongs to with respect to each of the 4 sides of the tetrahedron:

Each side is defined by 3 points (say A, B, C). Then a plane normal is a (C-A)x(B-A) (that's cross product of vectors in the plane). If this coordinates are (a,b,c), then the plane equation is `F(x,y,z) = ax+by+cz = 0`. For a given point (x0, y0, z0) the sign of F(x0,y0,z0) determines which half-plane the points belong to.

The point is that you can precompute plane quations for each side of the tetrahedron as well as the sign which corresponds to 'outside' an then the check for a given point amounts to doing at most 4 evaluations (one for each side), each taking 3 multiplications and 2 additions.

Comment: You can also scale the plane equations so that the value of $F$ is zero on the plane and 1 at the opposite vertex. That way all valid points have $0<=F(x,y,z)<=1$ - which means you get to discard more points for each plane.